# Why a static library can depend on a shared a library?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

As far as I know, a static library cannot depend on a shared library in Linux. However, when I compile a program that is linked to glog.a and gflags.a, the compiler reports the following errors:

```
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.a(libglog_la-utilities.o):
> In function `google::GetStackTrace(void**, int, int) [clone .part.7]':
> (.text+0xad): undefined reference to `_Ux86_64_getcontext'
> (.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_init_local'
> (.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_step' (.text+0x100):
> undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_get_reg' (.text+0x120): undefined
> reference to `_ULx86_64_step' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status
```

This compile error is resolved by linking unwind.so as well. But what I feel strange is why would libglog.a depends on a shared library? Isn't this impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This claim

> a static library cannot depend on a shared library in Linux

is completely wrong.

A static library is simply a collection of object files.

If you can have code using imports from a shared library that compiles to an `.o` file, you can collect those `.o` files into a library and now you have a library that uses imports from a shared library.

The only real difference that a static library makes, compared to linking all the object code directly, is that the library contains an index of symbols that the linker uses to decide which object files inside the library need to be linked.  Whereas object files directly passed to the linker are always linked in.  This has important ramifications for global initializer behavior and very little else.