# How to link static library depending on a shared library with CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to use static library(`libglog.a`) not shared with my `heartbeat` app.

The `glog` lib(https://github.com/google/glog) I used is depends on `unwind` lib **refer by this link** [Why a static library can depend on a shared a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66494921/8106621)

I also encountered this problem too ! @Ke Yang

But I am new to CMake, I don' know how to link `unwind.so` please?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```sh
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)

link_directories(

)

add_executable( heartbeat
    main.cpp
    heartbeat.cpp
    ${COMPONENTS_SRC}
    ${MODULES_SRC}
)
    
target_link_libraries( heartbeat 
    libpthread.a
    libcrypt.a
    libm.a

    libgflags.a
    libglog.a
    libhiredis.a
    libredis++.a
)

# 输出到build文件夹上层目录
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/..)
```

Then I get this ERROR

```sh
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.a(libglog_la-utilities.o)：在函数‘google::GetStackTrace(void**, int, int) [clone .part.7]’中：
(.text+0xad)：对‘_Ux86_64_getcontext’未定义的引用
(.text+0xb8)：对‘_ULx86_64_init_local’未定义的引用
(.text+0xe7)：对‘_ULx86_64_step’未定义的引用
(.text+0x100)：对‘_ULx86_64_get_reg’未定义的引用
(.text+0x120)：对‘_ULx86_64_step’未定义的引用
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: where does those lib come from? usually you have imported logical names on libs that you use for linkeage

Comment: seems you could use `find_package(glog REQUIRED)` and then link `glog::glog` in trget_link_libraries and glog should pull all its dependencies "automatically"